# AWS IoT parse_time function does not work when creating rule with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-iot

Why doesn't [parse_time](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html) function work when I create with CloudFormation this way?

```
  IoTTopicRule:
    Type: AWS::IoT::TopicRule
    Properties:
      TopicRulePayload:
        Actions:
          - DynamoDBv2:
              ...
        RuleDisabled: false
        Sql: |
          SELECT 
            clientid() as hashKey,
            concat('weather_', parse_time("YYYY-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss", timestamp())) as rangeKey,           
          FROM 'topic'
```

When data is saved on DynamoDB, `rangeKey` is saved as `weather_` and I expected that it'd be saved as `weather_2020-05-28T07:05:57`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

It's because CloudFormation creates the SQL query with the `2015-10-08` version and this version does not support `parse_time` function:

> Use the parse_time function to format a timestamp into a human-readable date/time format. Supported by SQL version 2016-03-23 and later.

Adding `AwsIotSqlVersion: '2016-03-23'` to template solves the issue.

```
  IoTTopicRule:
    Type: AWS::IoT::TopicRule
    Properties:
      TopicRulePayload:
        Actions:
          - DynamoDBv2:
              ...
        AwsIotSqlVersion: '2016-03-23'
        RuleDisabled: false
        Sql: |
          SELECT 
            clientid() as hashKey,
            concat('weather_', parse_time("YYYY-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss", timestamp())) as rangeKey,           
          FROM 'topic'
```